# OpenCV in Fullscreen mode changes video aspect ratio

Tags: python, c++, opencv

My video aspect ratio is 16:9 and my monitor is 16:10. I wrote this code for playing video in full screen mode but the problem is it causes my video to stretch. I want to keep its aspect ratio and have black bars on top and bottom (just like playing videos in KMPlayer)

Is there any solution?
Thanks

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

vid = cv2.VideoCapture('video.mp4')

cv2.namedWindow('My Window',cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
cv2.setWindowProperty('My Window',cv2.WND_PROP_ASPECT_RATIO,cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO)
cv2.setWindowProperty('My Window',cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)

while vid.isOpened():
    ret,frame = vid.read()

    cv2.imshow('My Window',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'): break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: I've tested your code, it works fine on my system (Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.6, OpenCV 3.4).

Comment: Thanks Salman. Your video and monitor have different aspect ratios? If yes, video is stretched or there are black bars on top and bottom?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't scratched and there is a white (not black) bar on top and bottom.

Comment: Thanks again. I use Windows 10 (v. 1709), Python 3.6, OpenCV 3.4. I think this is an issue with window. // Has someone else tested this code on windows?

Comment: I have the same problem on windows 10 with Python 3.6 and opencv-python 4.1.0.25